# Does $ \sum_{n\geq 2} \frac{\ln(1+n)}{\ln(n)}-1$ converge/diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, contest-math

How would you prove convergence/divergence of the following series?

$$ \sum_{n\geq 2}\left( \dfrac{\ln(1+n)}{\ln(n)}-1\right)$$

I'm interested in more ways of proving convergence/divergence for this series.

My thoughts

$$\dfrac{\ln(1+n)}{\ln(n)}=\frac{\ln(n(1+\dfrac{1}{n})}{\ln(n)}
=\frac{\ln(n)+\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\ln(n)}
=1+\frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\ln(n)}$$

then

$$\dfrac{\ln(1+n)}{\ln(n)}-1=\frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\ln(n)}$$

note that  $\ln(1+\frac 1n)=\frac 1n+o(\frac 1n)$ then $\ln(1+\frac 1n)\sim \frac 1n$ thus $u_n-1\sim \frac 1{n\ln(n)}$

or the serie $\dfrac{1}{n\ln(n)}$ divergent by Bertrand's test

the sum up $ \sum_{n\geq 2} \dfrac{\ln(1+n)}{\ln(n)}-1$ divergent

- Is my proof correct

Comment: Looks good. I don't see a mistake.

Comment: It depends on one's degree of fussiness. I am content, the key idea is well described. One might want to do a formal Limit Comparison with $\sum_2 \frac{1}{n\ln n}$.

Comment: For clarification: Is the summation to be interpreted as $-1+\sum\frac{\ln(1+n)}{\ln n}$ or $\sum\left(\frac{\ln(1+n)}{\ln n}-1\right)$? The answers suggest the latter.

Comment: $$\sum\left(\frac{\ln(1+n)}{\ln n}-1\right)$$

Answer (score 8):

One other way to see this is to note that
$$\frac{\ln(n+1)-\ln n}{\ln n}\ge \int_{\ln n}^{\ln(n+1)}\frac{dt}{t}$$
hence
$$\sum_{n=2}^m\frac{\ln(n+1)-\ln n}{\ln n}\ge\int_{\ln 2}^{\ln(m+1)}\frac{dt}{t}
>\ln(\ln(m+1))$$
and the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 6):

Also note, using the simple fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+1/n\right)^n =e$, that when $n$ large, we have

$$\dfrac{\ln(1+1/n)}{\ln(n)}=\dfrac{\ln(1+1/n)^n}{n\ln(n)}\approx \frac{1}{n \ln(n)}$$
where for getting the equality I mutiplied both numerator and denominator by $n$.

Comment: @  it's good idea

Answer (score 3):

A faster way of getting to the same series to apply the Limit Comparison Test uses the mean value theorem:
$$\ln(1+n) - \ln(n) \approx \frac{1}{n}$$
$$\frac{\ln(1+n)}{\ln(n)} - 1 \approx \frac{1}{n\ln n}.$$

Comment: I tired to use mean value theorem to gdt $\ln(1+n) - \ln(n) \approx \frac{1}{n}$ i took $$f(n)=\ln(n)\quad \exists n \text{ such that } \dfrac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{1}=f'(n)$$ could u add some details

Comment: Perhaps take a derivative? :~)

Comment: would u add some clarification please $f'(n)=\dfrac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 1):

There have already been several solid ways forward presented.  Here we use standard inequalities only.

To that end, we have the inequalities

$$\frac1{2n}<\frac{1}{n+1}\le\log\left(1+\frac1n\right) \tag 1$$

valid for $n\ge 2$.

Therefore, for $n\ge 2$, we have that

$$\frac{\log (n+1)-\log n}{\log n}\ge \frac{1}{(n+1)\log n} \ge \frac{1}{2n\log n} \tag 3$$

Inasmuch as the series on the right-hand side of $(3)$ diverges by the integral test, then the original series also diverges.  And we are done.

Comment: Thank u just give me time to understand ur way, i'm kind of asleep so if i didn't do tonight may be tomorow

Comment: @Educ No worry.  I just want to help.  ;-))

Comment: i know and Thank you so much for ur help

Comment: Please if u could provide detailed solution here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445661/properties-of-sum-limits-n-geq-1a-n-sum-limits-n-geq-1-dfrac1a-n1-s/1445669?noredirect=1#comment2944831_1445669

Comment: @educ Sure.  I posted an answer for that question.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
\begin{align}
\frac{\log(1+x)-\log(x)}{\log(x)}
\end{align}
is monotonically decreasing and positive when $x>1$. Applying Cauchy's condensation test, it suffices to look at
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{k=1}2^k\left( \frac{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{2^k}\right)}{k\log 2}\right).
\end{align}
Next, note that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}x\leq \log(1+x)
\end{align}
for $0\leq x\leq 1$, then we see that
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{k=1}2^k\left( \frac{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{2^k}\right)}{k\log 2}\right) \geq \frac{1}{2\log 2}\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{1}{k}=\infty. 
\end{align}
Hence it follows that the original series also diverges.