# Convergence of $\sum\limits_n\frac{1}{a_n+1}$ and $\sum\limits_n\frac{a_n}{a_n+1}$ when $\sum\limits_na_n$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

This is from an MCQ contest.

> Let  $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}a_n$ be a convergent series of positive terms. Which of the following hold?
>
> - $1]$ $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{1}{a_n+1}$ and $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{a_n}{a_n+1}$ are convergent.
> - $2]$ $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{1}{a_n+1}$ and $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{a_n}{a_n+1}$ are divergent.
> - $3]$ $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{1}{a_n+1}$ is Divergent and  $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{a_n}{a_n+1}$ is convergent
> - $4]$ none of the previous statements is correct

i come up with this conter example :

- $1]$ $\sum_{n\geq 1} \dfrac{1}{n^2}$ convergent  so let 's verify:
  $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{1}{a_n+1}=\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{n^2}{1+n^{2}}$

or $\lim_{n\to +\infty }\dfrac{n^2}{1+n^{2}}=1 \neq 0$ then $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{1}{a_n+1}$ divergent thus $1]$ False i don't need to verify $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{a_n}{a_n+1}$ because there is  'and' in the statement $1]$

- $2]$ in this case i need to check the nature of $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{a_n}{a_n+1}$

$\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{a_n}{a_n+1}=\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{1}{1+n^2}$
i don't know to calculate i use just Wolframe and it's convergent

- $3]$ i can't say that statement is true just becuase one example work i need to prove it but i don't now how
- Is my proof correct
- Is there any kind of reasoning one may use during a contest, when a quick answer is needed

Comment: Is $\sum a_n$ convergent?

Comment: @   yes of course

Answer (score 2):

From your solution of (1), I'll assume that $\sum a_n$ is convergent. If so, your argument for (1) is correct. For (2) and (3) (and also (1)) note that

1. $\displaystyle\frac{a_n}{a_n+1}<a_n$ so $\sum\dfrac{a_n}{a_n+1}$ is convergent.
2. $\dfrac{1}{a_n+1}\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$ so $\sum\frac{1}{a_n+1}$ is divergent.

I hope that also answers your last question. Though honestly I'd say there's no magic recipe in handling convergence of a series.

Comment: how can i prove that $\sum \dfrac{1}{a_n+1}$ convergent if $\sum a_n$ i can't prove it based in exampl

Comment: That's the [Comparison Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test), one of the basic, and probably the most commonly used, tests for convergence: *A positive series bounded above by a convergent series is convergent*.

Comment: you use that for $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{a_n}{a_n+1}$ not for $\sum \dfrac{1}{a_n+1}$ i'm talking about the latter

Comment: Ah, I saw *convergent*. The series $\sum\dfrac{1}{a_n+1}$ is *divergent*. Exactly as you argued in your question ($\sum a_n$ is convergent, so $a_n\to 0$).

Answer (score 2):

Much of the analysis in the OP was fine.  To add some thoughts, recall that if a series converges, then it's terms must approach zero as $n\to 0$.

Therefore, if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$.  This implies that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{1+a_n}=1$, which in turn implies that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+a_n}$ diverges.

Now, since $a_n\to 0$, then there exists a number $N$ so that $a_n<1$ whenever $n>N$.  Then, for such an $N$, $\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}<\frac12 a_n$.  Inasmuch as the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac12 a_n$ converges, then so does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$.

The answer is, therefore, number $3$.